# I want to run post and put method request in same test.is there any method for me to use in postman?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, postman

I want to run post and put  method  in same test.is there any method for me to use this in postman?.
Like if I can Add any script in Pre-Request so that there is no need for me to execute post method first and test put method separately.

Comment: Can you explain with example what are u trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can chain requests together by putting them within the same collection. Then [run the collection](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/starting_a_collection_run). They will execute in the order you put then in your collection. For conditional workflows you can use [setNextRequest](http://blog.getpostman.com/2016/03/23/conditional-workflows-in-postman/) in the test script of your `POST`request to invoke the `PUT`.

Currently you cannot make a request in either your pre-request script or in the test scripts. The scope of those scripting environments is defined in the [Postman Sandbox](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox).

Comment: Can i get any videos link for Postman Sand box so that it will be better for me to understand

Comment: Like this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=29-OtIS7I3o and https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test_scripts?